# Automatically scrolling panel

Tags: android

I need a panel which keeps scrolling horizontal automatically while the activity is running. Just like the scrolling bottom bar we see on Television ( on News etc.). Any idea on how to achieve this ? Thanks

Edit : I found out there are guides & libraries on this , seems that the word I needed was 'marquee'

Comment: you need something like this?: https://youtu.be/fwJqaGHoflE?t=5m42s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is `marquee` which is available on [Github](https://github.com/ayltai/Android-Lib-VerticalMarqueeTextView)

Comment: This looks like what I just need . Can I customize this to scroll horizontally?

Comment: I think you can, try changing the orientation of `LinearLayout` to `horizontal`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Vertical Marquee TextView for Android](https://github.com/ayltai/Android-Lib-VerticalMarqueeTextView) library with some changes.

First, download the library's source code and add it to your project.

Next, go to the class `VerticalMarqueeTextView` and make it extend `HorizontalScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.

Finally, change the `run` method of `MarqueeRunnable` as such -

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final int width = textView.getWidth();
        final int parentWidth = this.parent.getWidth();

        if (width > 0 && parentWidth > 0 && width > parentWidth) {
            if (this.textView.getScrollX() >= width) {
                this.textView.scrollTo(-parentWidth,0 );
            } else {
                this.textView.scrollBy(VerticalMarqueeTextView.this.unitDisplacement, 0);
            }

            this.textView.invalidate();
        }
    }
```

That's it.

It's also advised to change all the 'Vertical' refrences in the library's fields and methods to 'Horizontal', to indicate its current usage.

Note, this hasn't been tested thoroughly, but it does seem to work.